# Why index size different on same column

Tags: postgresql-9.3

We have created two same indexes on same column by mistakenly, But when we checked the size of indexes is two different later dropped one index.

Want to check why the size is showing different.

Example:

```
create index index1 on table1 using btree(column1);
create index index2 on table1 using btree(column1);

pega=> select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('index1')); 
pg_size_pretty 
---------------- 
100 MB 
(1 row) 

 select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('index2')); 
pg_size_pretty 
---------------- 
70 MB 
(1 row)
```

Could please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen after creating first index if any DML operations performed on that table, it will occupy the dead tuples and size will be increased, now if you create same index on that column size will show different than first index .

After performing vacuum full then sizes showing equally.

examples:

```
mydb=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('idx1'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 6600 kB
(1 row)

mydb=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('idx2'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2208 kB
(1 row)


mydb=# vacuum full temp1;
VACUUM
mydb=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('idx1'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2208 kB
(1 row)

mydb=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('idx2'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2208 kB
(1 row)
```